# ld: can't open output file for writing: execs/aligns, errno=2 for architecture arm64

Tags: c++, clang, apple-m1

I created a small program to learn some concepts of STL, but when I compile, I get following error:

```
ld: can't open output file for writing: execs/aligns, errno=2 for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Compiled with:

```
g++ --std=c++17 aligns.cpp -o execs/aligns
```

I am using M1 MacBook.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Have you tried compiling with `clang++` instead or do you need to use GNU `g++`? I faced similar error recently and `clang++` was successful on M1 where `g++` failed similarly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have finally found the solution!

Folder 'execs' simply didn't exist)))